# What does か + と do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> ベルの成長速度にアイズへの恋慕が**これまでかと影響した**「ステイタス」を見せつけられ、ちょっとも面白くなかったゆう昨夜。

Is the と here acting as a quotative particle? So it's 「これまでか」と影響した?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that と is the quotative particle, because that's a short for これまでかと言うほど.

これまでかと ("to this extent", "this much") as a whole modifies 影響した, and it describes how strongly the 恋慕 influenced the 成長速度.

A more common fixed expression similar to this is [これでもかと(言うほど)](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%8B), which works just like this and effectively means *strongly/badly/cruelly*.